# How to hide hardcoded limit in my application?

Tags: c#, .net

I am near release date for my Excel Add-In and I want to have only one limitation hardcoded in the code. My aim is for people to download and use the tool for free but have a limitation that potentially encourages them to buy the unlimited version. I know that there isn't a truly secure way to add that limitation but I was wondering what is the best way of achieving it. The limitation is simply a hardcoded value that I store in the Properties section of my app. Any ideas how I can make it a bit more secure?

Comment: Have you tried to obfuscate your code? It makes source unreadable.

Comment: I don't think there is any completely safe way, but try to encrypt the value and your code can then decrypt it

Comment: You can try ATL library in C++ for hardcoded values and call that dll in to your C# application.. That hardcoded value will be very secure because of C++....

Comment: This may be useful although I think ultimately the answer is you can never hide them perfectly: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164054.aspx

Comment: Oh I am going to obfuscate the code anyway because the algorithm behind the software is quite novel but I know that is not very secure either. Thanks for the comments

Comment: Best way would be to have them register then use a registration server which your application pings to check if the current user is registered and has purchased. That way you're not storing the limitation locally making it harder for people to circumvent. Creating an external registration server is additional work however and may be outside the scope of what you want to do. Could look at a 3rd party service - http://www.licensespot.com/ OR http://www.kagi.com/features/software-licensing OR http://www.licence-protector.com/ OR http://www.flexerasoftware.com/producer/

Comment: I looked at licencespot and seems to be a good solution but not for the time being. Its too early and I am not making any money out of this, just getting started.

Comment: In that case I'd suggest obfuscating it in your application somehow. This will prevent 95% of people from causing problems. You need to balance the cost/effort of implementing something 100% secure against the possibility/impact of it happening.